# Why is the last activity (GameOver) starting after screen unlock?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Basically, When i turn off screen (emulator Nexus 5x nougat), and turn it back on, no matter which activity was in the background of my app, the last activity GameOverScreen always gets to run after screen unlock.

I want whatever current background activity from my app activities to run instead, not always the gameoveractivity even tho its not selected at all as background!

so if these were letters A (not a layout), B, C, D, E and say B was running in background before i turn screen off on standby, when i turn it back on, whats happening is 'E' is coming up, not B as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue would most likely be caused by code in your onRestart/onStart/onResume of your activities since this is happening when the app comes from the background. Try looking at the parent activity to see if there is anything fishy in one of those life cycle methods. I'll need to see more code to be sure. Could you share MainScreenActivity since it seems that your activities are descendants of it.

EDIT:
It looks like

```
   @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        endGame();
    }
```

is your culprit.